# Homestead/Vagrant refusing Image manipulation

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I am running into a problem with Homestead. I have a piece of code that works well on an online dev server, but fails in the vagrant Homestead one.
The piece of code is an ajax executed one, where I upload an image, save it in a temp directory and send it back to the user, who then crops it. For this, I have two functions, tempUpload and tempCrop. It is failing in tempCrop, and most the line that triggers it is the following:

```
$img = getimagesize($imgUrl);
```

$imgUrl is an input with the url to an image in a temp folder. Checking in vagrant, I saw that these images have attributes -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant. The error appearing in the console is "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data".

Again, this works perfect in an online version, so I guess it is either a permission problem or some environment setting. The permissions for the temp folder in vagrant are as following: drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant

I have checked in /app/storage/logs, and the error I'm getting is:

```
'getimagesize(http://nominate.app:8000/temp/2078ec37e959dd733930ad758854ce4cb5f175de.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection refused'
```

I really don't know what else to look into, specially since it is working fine in another dev environment I have, running centOS.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be to put the *path* rather than the *url* into `getimagesize`.

Basically, as far as your virtual machine knows, it's serving on port 80.  Vagrant seamlessly forwards this port to the host machine's port 8000.  When you call `getimagesize`, it first tries to resolve the hostname (`nominate.app`), and, if successful, it tries to initiate a connection to it on port 8000.  I'm guessing that `nominate.app` is configured to resolve to `127.0.0.1` (the VM), which isn't actually listening on port 8000.

It's a bad idea to perform those sorts of operations over HTTP, since it'll slow things down and potentially generate multiple temporary copies of the same image.  You can use Laravel's [path helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#paths) to help you determine the local path of the image (i.e. `getimagesize(public_path() . "/temp/" . $filename)`).

Comment: THANKS A LOT!
Your solution worked like a charm. Most obliged ;)
Mariano

Comment: @MarianoAlesandro you should mark this as the answer. See this [post about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you don't know how/why.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my host file to point homestead.app to the Homestead VM's IP of 192.168.10.10 rather than 127.0.0.1 resolved this very same issue. Additionally, I can now navigate to http://homestead.app rather than http://homestead.app:8000.

Thanks to ClarkF for pointing me in the right direction to get this resolved!

As much as we don't enjoy "it works in develop but not in production", it's even more curious when it works in production but not in develop!