# Slow File Uploads on virtual machine using virtualbox with vagrant + homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

So i setup a virtual machine with vagrant using the virtual box container provided by laravel's homestead. (on my osx env)

I used the nfs option method of sharing my directories to my local environment and this speed up response times drastically.  On a typical app, i'm getting like 20-40ms load per page.  However, I noticed that file uploads are terribly slow.  I can upload a 1MB file on a simple form that does nothing to the file and it will take about a 30seconds to a minute.  Is this normal, or is there a way to speed things up even further besides using nfs shares.

Comment: If anyone is looking for speeding up your response times using the nfs option he is referring to, here it is: https://coderwall.com/p/2nak4q/use-nfs-to-speed-up-your-homestead-vm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that come to my mind:

- Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, find the "sendfile" setting and change it to "off" (I've seen some reports of people having some issues with it turned on when using NFS);
- Having xdebug enabled slows things down, and although I wouldn't expect it to make such a huge difference as the one you're noticing, if nothing else works it might be worth disabling it and see if helps;

If none of these help, create a repo on github to recreate the issue and I'll have a look, see if I find anything.

Comment: actually... false alarm..i got all excited cause i thought it had fixed it but i guess it didn't.  I'll try to post a repo soon to isolate the issue.

Comment: OK, let me know when you do and I'll try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just did a fresh install of Yosemite and I don't have the problem anymore.  There are times when its sort of slow but others when its fast.  I'll just live with it.

Answer (score 8):

This has been driving me crazy for some time, and no amount of toying with Vagrant's or VirtualBox's settings (sendfile, NFS, adjusting packet sizes, etc.) helped. But with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25415504/4043861) on a similar problem relating to failed image uploads, I've finally cracked it:

The key, for me, was changing my `hosts` file to resolve my Homestead domains to the homestead VM's IP of `192.168.10.10`, rather than to `127.0.0.1`. (When doing this, you also drop the port `:8000` from the URL, so you just navigate to `homestead.app`).

This changed my file upload speed from around 25 KB/sec to 5980 KB/sec!

It appears that the Laravel docs were updated a week ago to reflect this change. I wonder if your Yosemite install coincided with the docs change, and you set up your new box with `192.168.10.10` while your old hosts setup pointed to `127.0.0.1`.

Even though the Laravel docs have been corrected—so this issue shouldn't present itself for new Homestead installs—there are still a lot of tutorials floating around in the wild that suggest resolving Homestead domains to `127.0.0.1`. Hopefully this answer will help head off some aggravation!

Comment: This sounds about right.  I am using the private ip instead of my localhost ip.  On another note, i'm having another annoyance with vagrant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447926/why-doesnt-vagrant-clean-nfs-exports-file

Comment: Yes, I believe the slow uploads are a result of using localhost because your the virtual machine needs to wait for the upload data to be forwarded from your local port 8000 to the VM's port 80. Changing your domain to point your VM's private IP means the upload data goes to the VM more directly. (By the way, in the accepted answer, turning "sendfile" off for NFS—and, in fact, NFS itself—wouldn't have any bearing on this issue, since uploading a file to your vagrant box doesn't touch anything in the shared folder.)

Comment: Thanks @damiani, this totally worked for me. It's been driving me nuts.

FWIW, I also had to change some settings for my situation. In `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` I added:

`upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M`

And in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

`client_max_body_size 1024m;`