# Why doesn't vagrant clean nfs exports file?

Tags: vagrant

So I was shocked to realize that vagrant doesn't cleanup its exports to nfs via /etc/exports when I halt the machine.  Is this expected or normal behavior.  Is there anyway I can make vagrant clean it up so that when i halt it and launch another vagrant setup that uses nfs there aren't any conflicts with nfs shares. I have to do this manually right now.

Comment: What version of vagrant are you running? Seems that was added to 1.5.0, `synced_folders/nfs: NFS entries are pruned on every vagrant up, if there are any to prune. [GH-2738]`, but perhaps it's not working in your case?

Comment: The issue was discussed briefly [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2738), noting that exports gets cleaned only "if there is NFS shares defined". Not sure what that means.

Comment: I'm running Vagrant 1.6.5, it appears they are being removed on destruction but not halted or suspended. NFS shares aren't part of the provision process so it only seems logical that they should be removed when server is halted cause it has to remount the shares anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the reason there were conflicts is cause OSX or NFS have issues mounting shares from a parent directory of an existing share. So me blaming vagrant for not removing shares was incorrect although i'm still not entirely sure why they need to stay there when you halt the vm anyway.

My previous setup.

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 ee3f798c-5786-4ab8-8e98-9e20cede811c
"/Users/username/Code/app" 192.168.10.10 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 ee3f798c-5786-4ab8-8e98-9e20cede811c
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 5b85e6ec-04ac-4b0d-b7cd-a36b57a39bdd
"/Users/username/Code" 192.168.22.10 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 5b85e6ec-04ac-4b0d-b7cd-a36b57a39bdd
```

I had to change it to this so that nfs wouldn't throw an error to vagrant.

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 ee3f798c-5786-4ab8-8e98-9e20cede811c
"/Users/username/Code/app" 192.168.10.10 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 ee3f798c-5786-4ab8-8e98-9e20cede811c
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 5b85e6ec-04ac-4b0d-b7cd-a36b57a39bdd
"/Users/username/Code/app2" 192.168.22.10 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 5b85e6ec-04ac-4b0d-b7cd-a36b57a39bdd
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. Have you tried setting `nfs_export` to `false` so Vagrant doesn't mess with your `etc/exports` at all, and make sure both share entries are already in `etc/exports` when you `vagrant up`? Do you get the same error?